# Capybara, Ruby: Accessing attribute of found element with special characters in

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, capybara

Currently i am trying to get the content of an attribute of an capybara element in ruby. 
The attribute name is col-index. Now I want to access the attribute via

```
[:col-index]
```

The problem here is, that symbols don´t seem to accept characters like a **-** .
What can I do different here? I cannot change the attribute name and I think it is a simple ruby issue.

If you need more code, just tell me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed: I thought [:'col-index] is not the same as [:col-index] but it is. The reason it did not find the content was, that I was just on the wrong element :)

Comment: Note: you can also just pass a string, it doesn’t need to be a symbol